# Image size taken from Flutter Image_Picker plugin is way too big

Tags: image, plugins, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, flutter

I want to use auto-focus on the camera, which is available on the image_picker plugin. However, when I call:

```
var bytes = new File(imagePath);
var enc = await bytes.readAsBytes();
print(enc.length);
```

I got: 5121126

which takes at least 10 seconds when I want to encode into json to send to an API server:

```
var body = json.encode({
      'image' : enc
})
```

In contrast, with the camera plugin, my byte array is only 420685, which is 10 times smaller, but it doesn't have the auto-focus feature.

Can I get some advice on how to reduce the size of the byte array from image_picker? Thank you.

Comment: Adding `imageQuality` parameter in the ImagePicker plugin compresses the size. 
eg:  File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, imageQuality: 20);

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `camera` plugin has 3 default resolutions, and you are probably selecting or defaulting to a lower resolution (than the hardware's full resolution).

The `image_picker` plugin doesn't have these presets, but does have some optional arguments on the `pickImage` method (`maxWidth` and `maxHeight`). Experiment setting one or both of these to VGA type resolutions (640, 480, even 800, 600) to see if this reduces the size of the captured image.

There's also a package called `image` which would allow you to post-process the image. The sample on the main page does a resize, maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already checked out the ``image`` package and it's very slow also to decode the image bytes and does the resizing.

Comment: pickimage optional arguments-- is good for taking lower res. pics

Answer (score 21):

Adding small values for the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` parameter in the `ImagePicker` plugin compresses the size. Here is an example:

```dart
var fileFromCamera = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 480, maxWidth: 640);
```

Answer (score 17):

Now in the image_picker v. ^0.6.7+4 you also have the parameter 'imageQuality' and in the documentation you can see.. "*The `imageQuality` argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging from 0-100 where 100 is the original/max quality.*"

So, the final code could be like:

```
ImagePicker().getImage(
      source:ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 480,
      maxWidth: 640,
      imageQuality: 50
)
```