# How to compress/reduce image sizes while uploading in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to compress/reduce image sizes while uploading in Dart? I am trying to upload a 5MB image but I want to reduce its size while uploading. I am using Dart and Flutter.

Comment: you would want to decrease the resolution of the image before uploading. But keep in mind, that you cant get the resolution back after uploading. So you can _reduce its size permanently_ but you cant _only reduce its size while uploading_.

Comment: I don't mind about quality here. So, how to reduce resolution to reduce image size to make app faster.

Comment: What's the source of the image? If it's from the camera, it may be simplest to just capture the image in a lower resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453705/image-size-taken-from-flutter-image-picker-plugin-is-way-too-big/50454154#50454154

Comment: @Richard Heap As you can see from response of your answer, `image` library is slow to decode and resize image

Comment: Exactly, which is why I suggested trying to capture the original image in lower resolution. Is the source the camera?

Comment: @Richard Heap User can pick images from the gallery

Comment: Ok, you may have to work with opencv in a plug-in then.

Answer (score 6):

There is an [image manipulation package on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image). It even includes an example for exactly what you want to do.

```
import 'dart:io' as Io;
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read an image from file (webp in this case).
  // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
  // decoder.
  Image image = decodeImage(new Io.File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  new Io.File('thumbnail.png')
        ..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

Comment: This causing app to freeze.

Comment: Resizing the image is CPU intensive. You should run this in a separate Isolate so that the main Flutter thread isn't blocked. The first example demonstrates how to do this:

https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples

Comment: @MichaelM The library should include futures for ease of use.

Comment: Unable to compress or resize PNG images. Is there any options to compress and resize png images?

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436254/image-picker-compressing-is-not-supported-for-type-png-how-to-compress-the-ima**

Comment: @OliverDixon a simple Future still run at the same main isolate.

Answer (score 3):

**For Dart**

Use [**Image**](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package:

With this package , you can load an image, resize it, and save it as a png:

First, add `image` as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file.

**Usage** :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';
void main() {
  // Read an image from file (webp in this case).
  // decodeImage will identify the format of the image and use the appropriate
  // decoder.
  Image image = decodeImage(File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync());

  // Resize the image to a 120x? thumbnail (maintaining the aspect ratio).
  Image thumbnail = copyResize(image, width: 120);

  // Save the thumbnail as a PNG.
  File('thumbnail.png')..writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(thumbnail));
}
```

Don't use it if you would like to use this image in flutter . Use other solutions like **[flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)** or **[ResizeImage class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ResizeImage-class.html)**.

> **Q**：Dart already has image compression libraries. Why use native?
>
> **A**: For unknown reasons, image compression in Dart language is not efficient, even in release version. Using isolate does not solve the
> problem.

Answer (score 2):

I made this function to reduce image size, hope this helps you guys

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as IMG;

 Future<Uint8List> ReduceImageQualityAndSize(Uint8List image) async {
  
  int maxInBytes = 20000;
  Uint8List resizedData = Uint8List.fromList(image);

  IMG.Image? img = await IMG.decodeImage(image);
  int size = await image.lengthInBytes;
  int quality = 100;
  
  print("size max: " + maxInBytes.toString());
  print("size before: " + size.toString() + " bytes");
   
  while (size > maxInBytes && quality > 10) {
     // reduce image size about 10% of image, until the size is less than the maximum limit
    quality = (quality - (quality * 0.1)).toInt();
    int width = img!.width - (img.width * 0.1).toInt();
    IMG.Image resized = await IMG.copyResize(img, width: width);
    resizedData =
      await Uint8List.fromList(IMG.encodeJpg(resized, quality: quality));
    size = await resizedData.lengthInBytes;
    img = resized;
  }

  print("size after: " + size.toString() + " bytes");

  return resizedData;
}
```

this function causes freeze in UI, so optimal if using [IsolateWorker](https://pub.dev/packages/isolated_worker)

```
import 'package:isolated_worker/isolated_worker.dart';

  await IsolatedWorker()
      .run(ReduceImageQualityAndSize, imageUint8List)
      .then((value) {
    imageUint8List = value;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) package. You can compress images pretty easily

Example:

```
File compressedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(file!.path,
    quality: 20, percentage: 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to upload my file on server using dio

packages: 
[flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image) 
[dio: ^4.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

code->

```
File? compressedFile = profileImage.value == null
          ? null
          : await FlutterNativeImage.compressImage(
              profileImage.value?.path ?? '',
              quality: 20,
              percentage: 60);
```

and then

```
if (compressedFile != null)
      'profile_pic': await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(compressedFile.path),
```

inspired by **[Jordan Kotiadis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72753269/7760245)**