# image_picker: compressing is not supported for type PNG. How to compress the image files with extension .png?

Tags: flutter, image-processing, dart, file-upload, image-compression

**In order to compress .jpg file this code simply works.**

```
  File pickedFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  print('Size in kb: -> ' + (pickedFile.lengthSync() / 1000).toString());
  File compressedFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage( source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);
  print('Size kb: -> ' + (compressedFile.lengthSync() / 1000).toString());

  _uploadFile(compressedFile);
```

**But how to compress the image files which have the extension like .png ?**

**Error:**

```
D/ImageResizer( 6282): image_picker: compressing is not supported for type PNG. Returning the image with original quality
W/ExifInterface( 6282): Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
```

Comment: JPEG is a **lossy** format - it discards less important aspects of your image to make it smaller. PNG is **lossless** - it retains all the information from your original picture so lossy compression is not an option.

Comment: Can we rename png image to jpg before conversion ? Is that possible?

Comment: You can't *"rename"* it because PNG files and JPEG files have entirely different contents. You could *"convert"* it from PNG to JPEG but then you might get new issues because JPEGs cannot contain transparency so your images would immediately all become opaque. Convert from PNG to JPEG with **ImageMagick** in Terminal `magick input.png output.jpg`

Comment: Sorry, I want to convert the images for my dart project.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Base from the error, `image_picker` doesn't support png when compressing or changing the image quality. You can use [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) plugin which has support for PNG format.