# Reduce size image from bytes Uint8List

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image

I am using the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package to import images before uploading them to Firebase Storage, because it allows me to choose the formats what is not possible with image_picker.

I would like to be able to reduce the size of these images to reduce their weight. The [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) package allows to compress images but it is not available for Flutter Web.

How can I reduce the size of an image imported in Flutter Web knowing that the format is Uint8List?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72753227/12771945

Answer (score 2):

if you know the image type you can convert it to jpeg and then compress it using the flutter image package.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Future<List<int>> _pngToJpg(Uint8List pngBytes) async {
  final pngImage = img.decodePng(pngBytes);
  final pngImageResized = img.copyResize(pngImage!, width: 800);
  return img.encodeJpg(pngImageResized, quality: 90);
}
```

you can use any other decoder depending on your image type. Expect a freeze in UI. You can use compute to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) package to compress any data. The following is an example function taking `Uint8List` and compressing it:

```dart
Uint8List compress(Uint8List input) {
  final encoder = ZLibEncoder();
  return encoder.encode(input) as Uint8List;
}
```

You'll want to do this in a separate isolate since this could noticeably block your UI, but this won't make any difference if your application is web-only.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the solution isn't working, the image size doesn't change even if I play with the levels

Comment: @Lab Share what you're trying. Also try other compression methods other than zlib. I find it unlikely that you're getting *0* compression, unless your file is really small already or something.

Comment: I will try and share my results

Comment: This archive package is not working to compress image size.
@Lab have you found any solution