# Flutter resize image before upload

Tags: image, io, dart, flutter

I need to resize images before uploading to the server.

I am using io and image package.

```
import 'dart:io';  
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
```

using this function

```
uploadImages(File image_File) async {

    Img.Image image_temp = Img.decodeImage(image_File.readAsBytesSync());

    Img.Image resized_img = Img.copyResize(image_temp, 800);

    File resized_file = File('resized_img.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(resized_img));

    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(resized_file.openRead()));
    var length = await resized_file.length();

    var uri = Uri.parse("https://myserver.com/upload.php");

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename: p.basename("resized_image.jpg"));


    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
```

When I run this code, and the app just freezes and the images didn't upload to the server.

Comment: no errors in your debug console?

Comment: [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'thumbnail.jpg' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:647:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:491:5)
#2      _File.writeAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:616:31)

Comment: So the problem is that it cannot open the file called 'thumbnail.jpg'. Is this an asset or an image that was downloaded? Where is it looking for this image?

Comment: @user7380419 you can't access files in the filesystem like that directly. You have to use the [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) plugin to write the file in the app's temporary or application directory. In practice though, Richard's answer below is a much better option.

Comment: how can I convert resized_img to Unit8List?

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to write it to a file; you can send the resized image directly from memory.

```
uploadImages(File image_File) async {
  img.Image image_temp = img.decodeImage(image_File.readAsBytesSync());
  img.Image resized_img = img.copyResize(image_temp, 800);

  var request = new http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST',
    Uri.parse('https://myserver.com/upload.php'),
  );
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'file',
    img.encodeJpg(resized_img),
    filename: 'resized_image.jpg',
    contentType: MediaType.parse('image/jpeg'),
  );

  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  var response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

Note: when you import packages, you should use a lower case label (i.e. `img`). You'll need to import `package:http_parser` to get `MediaType` too.

Comment: Hi, thanks Richard! the function is working good, but it takes 2mins to resize one image, is it normal?

Comment: Yes. The image package runs in pure dart and isn't heavily optimized. Wherever possible, capture the image in lower resolution. See, for example [Image size taken from Flutter Image_Picker plugin is way too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453705/image-size-taken-from-flutter-image-picker-plugin-is-way-too-big/50454154)

Answer (score 3):

While i am using

```
package:image/image.dart
```

facing below issues

- showing blank page while converting image ( may be taking so much
  process while compressing image)
- After compression image was stretched and not looking good

Then used below plugin, same working fine without any issue, even faster and what i expected

https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git

steps and method available in above link.